# Offline google maps with .mbtiles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tiles, mbtiles

I have mbtiles file and I need to implement it into my google maps view in android. I cannot find a suitable tutorial for this, so, if anyone has something to offer, please share it with me...

Answer (score 1):

This library is what you need
https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons

use this snippet after adding library to you project:

```
// Retrieve GoogleMap instance from MapFragment or elsewhere
GoogleMap map;

// Create new TileOverlayOptions instance.
TileOverlayOptions opts = new TileOverlayOptions();

// Get a File reference to the MBTiles file.
File myMBTiles;

// Create an instance of MapBoxOfflineTileProvider.
MapBoxOfflineTileProvider provider = new MapBoxOfflineTileProvider(myMBTiles);

// Set the tile provider on the TileOverlayOptions.
opts.tileProvider(provider);

// Add the tile overlay to the map.
TileOverlay overlay = map.addTileOverlay(opts);

// Sometime later when the map view is destroyed, close the provider.
// This is important to prevent a leak of the backing SQLiteDatabase.
provider.close();
```

Comment: I've tried this and haven't had any success myself.

Comment: please notice that, this snippet is not just a `copy-paste-magic` you should read and do the comments, it has been working for me, for more than three years